# What was the user.agent value for IE11 edge? We are using gwt 2.4.0

Tags: gwt, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, gwt-2.4

I want to make my application compatible with IE11 and edge. I have xyz.gwt.xml file and I have to include compilation for IE 11 and Edge. We are using gwt 2.4.0.

set-property name="user.agent" value="ie6,ie8,gecko1_8"

Comment: Please define _IE11 Edge_.

Comment: I mean IE11 and Edge

Comment: @Teemu `user.agent` is a special property in GWT with a finite set of values (which incidentally is computed based on the `navigator.userAgent`, but also `document.documentMode`)

Answer (score 1):

I have checked it in GWT 2.7. It may be different in GWT 2.4:

IE11 is `gecko1_8`

Edge is `safari`

---

You can check it by yourself by:

- deleting/commenting out the `set-property name="user.agent"` entry in `<module>.gwt.xml` file (so, there will be no restrictions on the `user.agent`)
- starting super dev mode
- opening the host page in IE11 / Edge
- checking in the console, you'll get something like
  `binding: user.agent=safari` / `binding: user.agent=gecko1_8`

Comment: super dev mode didn't exist in GWT 2.4; it was first introduced in 2.5, but only became really usable in GWT 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

GWT 2.4 was released 7 years ago, IE11 two years later (even IE10 hadn't yet been released 7 years ago), and Edge two additional years later.

There's absolutely no guarantee that an app compiled with GWT 2.4 will continue to work in today's browsers (except in browsers that didn't change since then, i.e. IE9 and earlier; but they're now unsupported by their editor(s)). If you **need** to support IE11 and Edge, you really should update to the latest version of GWT (and, basically, update whenever a new version is released), which is currently 2.8.2.